# Problem with generic return type in guice assisted inject factory

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

So far, I successfully used google guice 2. While migrating to guice 3.0, I had troubles with assisted inject factories. Assume the following code

```
public interface Currency {}
public class SwissFrancs implements Currency {}

public interface Payment<T extends Currency> {}
public class RealPayment implements Payment<SwissFrancs> {
    @Inject
    RealPayment(@Assisted Date date) {}
}

public interface PaymentFactory {
    Payment<Currency> create(Date date);
}

public SwissFrancPaymentModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
             .implement(Payment.class, RealPayment.class)
             .build(PaymentFactory.class));
    }
}
```

While creating the injector, I get the following exception:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Payment<Currency> is an interface, not a concrete class.
   Unable to create AssistedInject factory. while locating Payment<Currency>
   at PaymentFactory.create(PaymentFactory.java:1)
```

With the assisted inject creator from guice 2 my configuration works:

```
bind(PaymentFactory.class).toProvider(
FactoryProvider.newFactory(PaymentFactory.class, RealPayment.class));
```

The only workaround I found so far is to remove the generic parameter from the return type of the factory method:

```
public interface PaymentFactory {
    Payment create(Date date);
}
```

Does anybody know, why guice 3 doesn't like the generic parameter in the factory method or what I generally misunderstood about assisted inject factories? Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering if you should be passing a `TypeLiteral<Payment<Currency>>` instead of `Payment.class` into the `implement`?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler Thanks, but how would you do that? `TypeLiteral` doesn't have a public constructor and if you use `TypeLiteral.get(Payment.class)`, you get the same exception.

Comment: Maybe this?`TypeLiteral.get(Types.newParameterizedType(Payment.class,Currency.class));`

Comment: A generic `TypeLiteral` should be created like: `new TypeLiteral<Payment<Currency>>(){}`. Note the `{}`... a subclass must be created for the full generic information to be available.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler: No, that does not work. There is a type mismatch when using your suggested `TypeLiteral` with the `implement` method.

Comment: @ColinD That doesn't work either. Also because of a type mismatch with the `implement` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two issues with your code above.

First, `RealPayment` implements `Payment<SwissFrancs>`, but `PaymentFactory.create` returns `Payment<Currency>`. A `Payment<SwissFrancs>` cannot be returned from a method that returns `Payment<Currency>`. If you change the return type of `create` to `Payment<? extends Currency>`, then `RealPayment` will work (because it's a `Payment` for something that extends `Currency`).

Second, you DO need to use the version of `implement` that takes a `TypeLiteral` as its first argument. The way to do that is to use an anonymous inner class. To represent `Payment' you can use

```
new TypeLiteral<Payment<? extends Currency>>() {}
```

See the Javadoc for that `TypeLiteral` constructor for more information.